# JDOM duplicate element name handling

Tags: java

Say for eg I have an XML like this

```
    <Containers>
      <Container  ContainerGrossWeight="0.69"  ContainerGrossWeightUOM="lbs" ContainerScm="16757598166153847" TrackingNo="420913119102999949374063023016">
      </Container>
    <Container   ContainerGrossWeight="4.84" ContainerGrossWeightUOM="lbs" ContainerScm="16757598166153848" 
    TrackingNo="420913119102999949374063023016">
      </Container>
    </Containers>
```

So "Containers" is the parent and it has two children..  and another .. But the attribute values in both  are different.

I use JDOM to read and manipulate the values. If I write the below code I get the attributes of first . My question is how do I access the attributes and values of second ?

```
Element Containers = rootNode.getChild("Containers")

Element Container = Containers.getChild("Container")

String ContainerSCM = Container.getAttributeValue("ContainerSCM")
```

The above code gives me "16757598166153847" as output
how do I get "16757598166153848" as output which is the getAttributeValue of second  Element Containers attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Element.getChildren()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#getChildren%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve all the `Containers` children named `Container` into a `List<Element>` then take the second.

```
List<Element> containers = rootNode.getChild("Containers").getChildren("Container");
Element secondContainer = containers.get(1); // take the second one
String secondContainerSCRM = secondContainer.getAttributeValue("ContainerSCM");
```

Or you could use [XPath](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/xpath/package-summary.html) to select directly the element you want using `//Containers/Container[2]`.